# Are there any cognitive models for image interpretation?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, vision

Are there any cognitive models which can be used for image interpretation. I have tried to find some specific models which can be used for image interpretation but have not been able to find any model.

Comment: How are you defining  "image interpretation"? There are big literatures on a range of topics such as visual categorisation, visual discrimination, aesthetic judgements, etc.

Comment: we want to categorize the features visually present in an image.we want to discriminate between the features in the images

Comment: Like @JeromyAnglim noted, there are entire fields related to this broad topic. It would be helpful to specify more details in your question.

Comment: i am willing to know the models which have been developed in the for cognitive image interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried to find some specific models which can be used for image
> interpretation but have not been able to find any model.

This question is broad and as you have stated that you have failed to find models, I thought I would provide you with references where visual cognition is researched.

The [UCL Institute of Cognitive Neuroscience](http://www.icn.ucl.ac.uk/Research-Groups/Visual-Cognition-Group/)   has a visual cognition group.

> The research in this group is concerned with detection, discrimination and short-term memory of visual stimuli. A key part of the approach to the work is to study interactions between different regions of visual cortex, and interactions between visual and non-visual areas by using transcranial magnetic stimulation, psychophysics, eye movements and electrophysiological recording methods. Human vision is a dominant force in our behaviour and the study of vision therefore takes research questions into many different areas of perception outside of our more obviously visual work on visual search, the functions of the parietal cortex, the frontal eye fields and how the brain changes with learning. These include the perception of time, visuomotor learning, music, and mathematics - apparently different functions which often draw upon the same brain resources. The group is engaged in extending the use of TMS in combination with other methodologies, in particular electrophysiological recording and work with neuropsychological patients.

This [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perception) entry on perception; discusses how perception between individuals has a wide variation, including the ability to interpret  visual cues.

The [Duke Visual Cognition Laboratory](https://web.duke.edu/perception/publications.html) has extensive research articles about this topic. I have provided some suitable excerpts.

> The visual system has developed to transform an undifferentiated and continuous flow of information into discrete and manageable representations, and this ability rests primarily on the uninterrupted nature of the input. <sub>1</sub>
>
> Recent laboratory work has indicated that low target prevalence can lead to disturbingly high miss rates in visual search. <sub>2</sub>
>
> Change blindness, the failure to detect visual changes that occur during a disruption, has increasingly been used to infer the nature of internal representations. If every change were detected, detailed representations of the world would have to be stored and accessible. However, because many changes are not detected, visual representations might not be complete, and access to them might be limited. Using change detection to infer the completeness of visual representations requires an understanding of the reasons for change blindness. This article provides empirical support for one such reason: change blindness resulting from the failure to compare retained representations of both the pre- and postchange information. Even when unaware of changes, observers still retained information about both the pre- and postchange objects on the same trial. <sub>3</sub>
>
> The input to visual processing consists of an undifferentiated array of features which must be parsed into discrete units. Here we explore the degree to which conscious awareness is important for forming such object representations, and for updating them in the face of changing visual scenes. <sub>4</sub>

There is a wealth of information here, it's quite fascinating. I hope you enjoy this, and feel free to come back with the questions you have about this.

<sub>1. Appelbaum, L. G., Cain, M. S., Schroeder, J. E., Darling, E. F., & Mitroff, S. R. (2012). Stroboscopic visual training improves information encoding in short-term memory. Attention, Perception, & Psychophysics.

2. Fleck, M. S., & Mitroff, S. R. (2007). Rare targets are rarely missed in correctable search. Psychological Science, 18, 943-947.

3. Mitroff, S. R., Simons, D. J., & Levin, D. T. (2004). Nothing compares 2 views: Change blindness can occur despite preserved access to the changed information. Perception & Psychophysics, 66, 1268-1281.

4. Mitroff, S. R. & Scholl, B. J. (2005). Forming and updating object representations without awareness: Evidence from motion-induced blindness. Vision Research, 45(8), 961-967.</sub>